Why is my JavaScript fetch API call returning a CORS error even though I've set up CORS on the server?
I'm working on a web application where I need to fetch data from an API hosted on a different domain. I'm using the fetch API in my JavaScript code, but I keep getting a cors error. Here is my client-side code:
app.js:
The error message I'm getting is:
Access to fetch at 'https://api.example.com/data' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
On the server side, I've set up CORS to allow requests from my development server:
server.js (Node.js with Express):
enter image description here
Despite setting up CORS on the server, I'm still encountering the error. I've verified that the server is running and accessible. What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

I take it api.example.com is a placeholder for some real domain you own

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Your express probably needs middleware like this.
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'

export function config(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
    if (req.headers.origin) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)
    } else {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    }
}

You can get extra information from:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
